# How to conditionally set values at a particular position along a particular axis of a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, axis

I'm looking for an efficient, pythonic way to set the nth value along a single axis in an ndarray according to a conditional test.  Here's an example.

Initial ndarray:

```
array([[[111, 112, 113, 114],
        [121, 122, 123, 124]],

       [[211, 212, 213, 214],
        [221, 222, 223, 224]],

       [[311, 312, 313, 314],
        [321, 322, 323, 324]]])
```

I would like to test items in the 2 position along the innermost axis (axis 2) so, in other words, all of the numbers in this example that happen to end in 3.  If the number is below a cutoff value, we'll say 215, then set the value to 0.

The result would look like:

```
array([[[111, 112, 0, 114],
        [121, 122, 0, 124]],

       [[211, 212, 0, 214],
        [221, 222, 223, 224]],

       [[311, 312, 313, 314],
        [321, 322, 323, 324]]])
```

I have tried combinations of Boolean indexing, numpy.where, etc. but isolating the nth item along a particular axis while using fancy indexing seems to be at least one level of complication beyond any examples I can find.  I hope this makes for an interesting question and I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access all the 2nd columns along the axis 0, use `[:,:,2]` (or `a[...,2]`):

```
a[:,:,2]

array([[113, 123],
       [213, 223],
       [313, 323]])
```

To change these values based on some condition (e.g. < 215) you can do the following:

```
mask = a[:,:,2] < 215
a[:,:,2][mask] = 0
```

Result:

```
array([[[111, 112,   0, 114],
        [121, 122,   0, 124]],

       [[211, 212,   0, 214],
        [221, 222, 223, 224]],

       [[311, 312, 313, 314],
        [321, 322, 323, 324]]])
```

Comment: That's It!  I was about an inch away from that several times but I never fully doubled-down on the [:,:,2].  Thank you!  (Up-voted).  I can't imagine a simpler, more elegant solution but I will leave the question open for a bit in case someone chimes in about efficiency or computational cost (my actual arrays have 44 million elements).